# Filter Pandas DataFrame by comparing columns in a row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Each row in my DataFrame has two date columns. How can I filter out the rows in which 'Date A' is after 'Date B'?

Example:

```
symbol |    reports_at       |    as_of        |      signal   
...   
A     | 2012-02-15T21:00:00Z |  2012-02-01T12:00:00Z|   65.20464367   
...
```

This row should be deleted from the DataFrame because the date in the 'reports_at' column occurs after the date in the 'as_of' column

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) or [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

**1.**

```
df1 = df[df['as_of'] > df['reports_at']]
```

**2.**

```
df1 = df.query('as_of > reports_at')
```

**3.**

```
df1 = df[df['reports_at'] <= df['as_of']]
```

**4.**

```
df1 = df.query('reports_at <= as_of')
```